# Equality & Inequality of two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, equality, inequality

For an assignment I have to overload several operators and use them in regards to two sets. I have my class, Set, which has two objects, A and B, both of which are set arrays. I am attempting to overload an equality and inequality function that will compare the elements in each set and output whether or not they are equal. The function should take the object Set B as an argument, and will compare Set A and Set B. While my program does compile, it continually outputs that my sets are not equal, both when I input two equal sets, and when I input two sets that are not equal. I've tried tweaking my functions around for hours but I haven't had any luck. Any help is much appreciated!

```
 bool Set::operator==(Set B){


    for (int i=0; i < pSize; i++){

            bool retstat = false;

            if(set[i] == B.set[i]){

                    cout <<"equal" << endl;
            }
            else
                    bool retstat = false;
                    cout <<"not" << endl;

            return (retstat);
    }


}




bool Set::operator!=(Set B){

    bool retstat = false;

    for(int i=0; i < pSize; i++){

            if(set[i] != B.set[i]){
                    retstat = true;
                    cout <<"not equal" << endl;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `{}` braces in your `else` branch, that's why `cout <<"not" << endl;` is always printed.

Comment: well for your `==` overload, you never set your `retstat = true` in your if block so it will never return true. you also reinitialize it every single tile (you dont need to have the `bool` before you call it in your else block. I would suggest declaring it outside the for loop as `true`

Comment: for your second code, you dont return anything...

Comment: Tip: `a != b` is (should be) equivalent to `!(a == b)`; `a == b` to `!(a != b)`, so you can reuse one operator to implement the other.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use names that are reserved by the C++ standard library (i.e., `set`).

Secondly, your for loop returns in the first loop (i.e., is wrong), also you reinitialize your "found" flag in the body of your loop.

Thirdly, pass your object in your overloaded operator by reference.

Fourthly, make your overloaded operators free functions in order to be symmetrical and make them friend of your class to be able to have access to its private members.

Last but not least. If you want to compare two arrays for equality use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

```
bool Set::operator==(Set const &B) {
  return std::equal(set, set + pSize, B.set, B.set + B.pSize);
}

bool Set::operator!=(Set const &B) {
  return !std::equal(set, set + pSize, B.set, B.set + B.pSize);
}
```

Comment: As a side note: Don't use the term STL for the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Your operator== are wrong, you have 2 `retstat`, you never affect it with true, you test only the 1st.
Review your code, and first test if the two set have the same size.